# Swift UnsafeMutablePointer & UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<SomeType>>

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use NSView's `getRectsBeingDrawn` and I'm not too sure as to how to cast the vars that it needs.

The definition of it is:

```
func getRectsBeingDrawn(rects: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<NSRect>>, count: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>)
```

I've defined both `rects` and `count` as:

```
var rects: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<NSRect>> = nil            
var count: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int> = nil
```

which seems to work. The debugger doesn't come up with anything handy for seeing what's at the pointers so that's no help.

`rect` should point to an array of NSRect after `getRectsBeingDrawn` is called, but it seems to return nothing. Also how do I get the array and int which rects and count are pointing to?

I'm trying to get a piece of code from the Apple sample "TableViewPlayground" to work in swift.

```
- (void)drawSelectionInRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    NSColor *primaryColor = [[NSColor alternateSelectedControlColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    NSColor *secondarySelectedControlColor = [[NSColor secondarySelectedControlColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

// Implement our own custom alpha drawing
    switch (self.selectionHighlightStyle) {
        case NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleRegular: {
            if (self.selected) {
                if (self.emphasized) {
                    [primaryColor set];
                } else { 
                    [secondarySelectedControlColor set];
                }
                NSRect bounds = self.bounds;
                const NSRect *rects = NULL;
                NSInteger count = 0;
                [self getRectsBeingDrawn:&rects count:&count];
                for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    NSRect rect = NSIntersectionRect(bounds, rects[i]);
                    NSRectFillUsingOperation(rect, NSCompositeSourceOver);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        default: {
            // Do super's drawing
            [super drawSelectionInRect:dirtyRect];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've managed to suss this out... I wasn't allocating the memory properly for `rects` and `count`

What I had was:

```
var rects: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<NSRect>> = nil
var count: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int> = nil
```

What ultimately fixed the issue was:

```
var rects: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<NSRect>> = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<NSRect>>.alloc(1)
var count: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int> = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(1)
```

Hope this helps someone else :)

*edit* If anyone is interested, here's what the swift code for the above turned out to be:

```
override func drawSelectionInRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    var primaryColor = NSColor.alternateSelectedControlColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
    var secondarySelectedControlColor = NSColor.secondarySelectedControlColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)

    switch (self.selectionHighlightStyle){
    case .Regular:
        if (self.selected){
            if self.emphasized{
                primaryColor.set()
            }else{
                secondarySelectedControlColor.set()
            }
            let bounds = self.bounds

            var rects: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<NSRect>> = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<NSRect>>.alloc(1)
            var count: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int> = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(1)

            self.getRectsBeingDrawn(rects, count: count)

            let rectArrayPtr = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: rects, count: count.memory)
            var base = rectArrayPtr.baseAddress

            for var i = 0; i < count.memory; i++ {
                var currentRect = base.memory
                let rect = NSIntersectionRect(bounds, currentRect.memory)
                NSRectFillUsingOperation(rect, .CompositeSourceOver)
                base.successor()
            }

        }
    default:
            super.drawSelectionInRect(dirtyRect)
        }
}
```

*edit*

As per a further comment, the same has been achieved here with a less verbose approach (thanks to Paul Patterson below):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536855/using-getrectsbeingdrawn-with-swift

Comment: This didn't work for me, so I asked a separate question. The answer I got suggested a less verbose approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536855/using-getrectsbeingdrawn-with-swift.

Comment: Out of interest what result did you get? (also updated my answer with your post.

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite remember what result I got, but I seem to remember that whilst it reported the correct number of rectangles, I could only access one of them.