# Using getRectsBeingDrawn: with Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsview, drawrect

I'm trying to use the `NSView` call `getRectsBeingDrawn(_:count:)` in a Swift app, but can't fathom how to unpack the 'return' values - the method's signature is particularly arcane. I'm getting the expected number of rectangles via the `count` variable, but I've no idea how to get access to rectangles in the array. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311166/swift-unsafemutablepointer-unsafemutablepointerunsafepointersometype) addresses the same issue, and proposes a solution, but it's not working for me - I can't get access to `NSRect` structs.

```
func decideWhatToRedraw() {

    let r1 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 20)
    let r2 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 35, height: 15)

    setNeedsDisplayInRect(r1)
    setNeedsDisplayInRect(r2)
}

override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    var rects: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<NSRect>> = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<NSRect>>.alloc(1)
    var count: Int = 0
    getRectsBeingDrawn(rects, count: &count)

    // count -> 2
    // But how to get the rects?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
var rects = UnsafePointer<NSRect>()
var count = Int()
getRectsBeingDrawn(&rects, count: &count)

for i in 0 ..< count {

    let rect = rects[i]

    // do things with 'rect' here

}
```

You make two variables `rects` and `count`, and pass references to both of them, so they get filled with information.

After calling `getRectsBeingDrawn`, `rects` points to `count` rectangles, which you can access with a subscript, like an array.

Comment: Ace! - Thanks. I'll update the question I referenced to point out this much more straight-forward (and successful) approach.

Comment: Swift 4: `init() is unavailable: use nil literal`

Answer (score 0):

swift 3.2

```
            var rects: UnsafePointer<NSRect>?
            var count = Int()

            getRectsBeingDrawn(&rects, count: &count)
            for i in 0 ..< count {
                let rect = NSIntersectionRect(bounds, rects![i]);
                NSRectFillUsingOperation(rect, NSCompositeSourceOver)
            }
```